# Sublime Text broke my code on Python while encoding

Tags: python, sublimetext

Sublime Text broke my code on Python while I was trying to encode it and that's what happened(this is not all code):

00c2 93c3 84c2 a3c3 8400 00c2 8dc4 8ac2
85c3 82c4 a500 c28d 00c4 a5c4 8ac2 8500
c293 c384 c29b c384 c280 00c2 8dc3 a2c2
88c2 9100 c29f c48a c2a4 c382 c4a5 c384
0000 c293 00c2 a4c3 84c2 80c4 8ac2 bdc3

Does anybody know, can I fix it or my code is over?

Comment: Trying to encode it? Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Yes, but outputs the same. I was trying to reopen this code with other encoding, аfter that, I wanted to return everything back, but these letters and numbers appeared

Comment: Still not 100% clear but there is a File > Reopen with Encoding menu option, if that helps.

Comment: Also I tryed to undo revert but didn't help

Comment: It looks like you have null bytes in the file and because the default setting for enable_hexadecimal_encoding is true, Sublime will open files containing null bytes as hexadecimal.

Comment: What was the encoding you originally used when you typed in the code? After it was converted to hex, did you make *any* changes to the code?

Comment: I used UTF-8 and I didn't change anything in the code